# Slide Out Panel that appends to a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

I'm attempting to create a slide out panel that appends to the container div within the header and footer of my page. I'm using Bootstrap for responsive, so the solution should ideally work with the media-queries contained within that package. I'm really at a loss on how to approach this because everything I've tried doesn't seem to work in some way or another.

This picture animates best what I'm trying to accomplish (sorry not a designer): 
http://d.pr/i/DzQc+

What I've tried:

**Pageslide** - this is was the closest solution I've found so far. this appends the slide out panel to the body. As such it doesn't allow me to keep the slide out panel within the header/footer container of the page: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/

**jQuery Mobile Panel Widget** - I tried to hack and repurpose the jQuery mobile panel widget plugin to function as desired without any luck.

**.append Function** - I tried to animate the .append function but this didn't work with the responsive functions of bootstrap.

With that all said, do any of you have a suggestion on a plugin, function or implementation that may work? I'm not necessarily looking for a working piece of code, rather I'm looking for a direction that will work as I'm hoping.

Thanks!

Comment: Just search for "javascript side menu".. I give you some in hope they can help you http://www.berriart.com/sidr/ https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/ https://github.com/acolangelo/jPanelMenu

Comment: I believe all of those append to the body element and push existing content within the body element to the left/right. They don't append to a specific div.

Comment: @viablepath Hey, you're picture is down.

Comment: @viablepath I see that the pageslide plugin simply adds a margin to the left/right of the document. Why not tweak the source so that you can also use top/bottom margins?

Comment: I agree, I think you'll have to tweak the source of the js/css plugin to achieve what you want to do, check out sidr, i've implemented it within bootstrap before

Answer (score 0):

Here is a popup container in a prototype pattern I built that you can create to any div.  CSS it up to style to your liking

Useage:

```
InfoPopup.Create('YourDivID');
InfoPopup.Destroy();
InfoPopup.Bounce();
$(InfoPopup.YesBtn).fadeIn();
$(InfoPopup.NoBtn).fadeIn();
$(InfoPopup.ShowBtn).fadeIn();
```

Ect...

```
InfoPopup = {
YesBtn:'',
NoBtn:'',
ShowBtn:'',
IdlBtn:'',
HintText:'',
Create:function(target, contentId){

    var infoImage = "";
    var infoWrapperDiv = document.createElement('div');
    infoWrapperDiv.id = 'infoWrapperDiv';
    //min-max  button
    var minMax = document.createElement('img');
    minMax.src = "images/minimize.png"
    minMax.id = 'infoPopupMinMax';
    minMax.setAttribute('onClick','InfoPopup.Shrink();');
    infoWrapperDiv.appendChild(minMax);
    //content
    var contentDiv = document.createElement('div');
    contentDiv.id = 'infoPopupContent';
    contentDiv.innerHTML = '<span>Some Stuff Here</span>'
    infoWrapperDiv.appendChild(contentDiv);
    //YesNoButtons - append to infoWrapperDiv if needed in specific activity
    //----  set custom onClick for the specific Activity in the switch
    this.YesBtn = document.createElement('input');
    this.YesBtn.id = 'infoBtnYes';
    this.YesBtn.setAttribute('value','Yes');
    this.YesBtn.setAttribute('type','button');
    this.YesBtn.className = 'inputButton';

    this.NoBtn = document.createElement('input');
    this.NoBtn.id = 'infoBtnNo';
    this.NoBtn.setAttribute('value','No');
    this.NoBtn.setAttribute('type','button');
    this.NoBtn.className = 'inputButton';

    this.ShowBtn = document.createElement('input');
    this.ShowBtn.id = 'infoBtnShow';
    this.ShowBtn.setAttribute('type','button');
    this.ShowBtn.setAttribute('value','Show');

    this.IdlBtn = document.createElement('input');
    this.IdlBtn.setAttribute('type','button');

    this.HintText = document.createElement('div');
    this.HintText.className = 'infoPopupHint';



    switch(contentId){//Remove switch to just set up the content
        case 1://on a 1 page web app the activity will dictate what content is presented 
            this.YesBtn.setAttribute('onClick','currentActivityObject.SaveVerification(1);');
            this.NoBtn.setAttribute('onClick','currentActivityObject.SaveVerification(0);');
            this.YesBtn.style.display = 'none';
            this.NoBtn.style.display = 'none';
            infoWrapperDiv.appendChild(this.YesBtn);
            infoWrapperDiv.appendChild(this.NoBtn);
            this.ShowBtn.setAttribute('onmousedown',"currentActivityObject.ShowAnswer(1);");
            this.ShowBtn.setAttribute('onmouseup',"currentActivityObject.ShowAnswer(0);");
            this.ShowBtn.className = 'inputButton infoBottomLeft';
            this.ShowBtn.style.display = 'none';
            infoWrapperDiv.appendChild(this.ShowBtn);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }
    infoWrapperDiv.appendChild(this.HintText);
    $id(target).appendChild(infoWrapperDiv);

    $('#infoWrapperDiv').animate({top:"78%"},'fast').animate({top:"80%"},'fast');
},
Shrink:function(){

    $('#infoWrapperDiv').animate({top:"90%"},'fast').animate({top:"88%"},'fast');
    var minMax = document.getElementById('infoPopupMinMax');
    minMax.setAttribute('onClick','InfoPopup.Grow();')
},
Grow:function(){

    $('#infoWrapperDiv').animate({top:"78%"},'fast').animate({top:"80%"},'fast');
    var minMax = document.getElementById('infoPopupMinMax');
    minMax.setAttribute('onClick','InfoPopup.Shrink();')
},
Bounce:function(){

$('#infoWrapperDiv')
    .animate({top:"90%"},'fast')
    .animate({top:"80%"},'fast');

},
Destroy:function(){

  var infoWrapperDiv = $id('infoWrapperDiv');
  if(infoWrapperDiv){
      infoWrapperDiv.parentNode.removeChild($id('infoWrapperDiv'));
   }
 }
};
```